# Proof of $|\int _a ^b \mathbf f | \leq \int _a ^b |\mathbf f|$

Tags: integration, inequality

Let $\mathbf f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R ^n$ be continuous. I'm trying to prove the following fact:
$$|\int _a ^b \mathbf f| \leq \int _a ^b |\mathbf f|,$$
where: $$|\mathbf x|^2=\sum _{i=1} ^n x_i ^2.$$
I understand it by intuition: if $\mathbf f$ is interpreted as the velocity of a particle in $\mathbb R ^n$, the first member is the length of the displacement  $\mathbf F(b)-\mathbf F(a)$, while the second one is the lenght of the described curve.

Since :$$|\int _a ^b \mathbf f|^2=\sum _{i=1}^n (\int f_i)^2$$
and $$(\int _a ^b |\mathbf f|)^2=(\int _a ^b \sqrt{\sum _i f_i ^2})^2,$$
I see that this is equivalent to prove the inequality for the second two members. Well... I'm stuck there. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proof I've found on Rudin, valid for $\mathbf f\in \mathscr R(\alpha)$:

Let $\mathbf y = \int _a ^b \mathbf f \, \text d \alpha$. Then: $$|\mathbf y|^2 =\sum y_i^2=\sum y_i \int _a ^b f_i \,\text d \alpha=\int _a^b(\sum y_if_i )\,\text d \alpha=\int_a ^b\mathbf y\cdot \mathbf f\,\text d \alpha$$
Using Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality on $\mathbf y\cdot \mathbf f$ proves the result.